# Live Agent Preview of Chat before Agent Accepts the chat in Omni Channel Lightning

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, omnichannel

I know that in Salesforce Classic when an agent gets a new live agent request, they can hover over the request to see a preview before the agent accepts the request.
[image]

I was wondering if I can do this in lightning in omni-channel? I know that in omni-channel, you get something like this, but it only shows the chat button, the depoyment name, the ip address and the name of the contact and nothing more.